# I want to printout my vector from vector list

Tags: c++, list, vector

I want to printout my vector from vector list

```
std::list < std::vector< unsigned int >> lista; 

for (std::list< std::vector< unsigned int > >::iterator i = lista.begin(); i != lista.end(); ++i){
    std::cout << std::hex << whats_here << " " << std::endl;
}
```

I don't know what should I place on *whats_here*. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it is time to a) pay attention during the lecture b) Read the lecture notes c) Go to the lecture

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

```
for (auto &list_item : lista)
{
    for (auto &item : list_item)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << item << " " << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Make any required adjustment to get the desired output. Since the expected output is not given in the question, the above code is my best guess given your non working code.